# CSS transition to make a border go away (the border appears on :active)

Tags: html, css, border

I'm not sure I can explain my problem very well since I'm still a newbe so I've made a JSfiddle of my code.

The problem is that when my div is active (or clicked), a border appears with a nice transition that I've set.

But when the div is not active anymore, the border has no transition when it disapears : it just vanishes in a blink of an eye.

So I would like to be able to have a transition when the border appears AND when it goes away.

Can you help me ? Thanks in advance !

```
<div class="square"></div>

*{
box-sizing:border-box;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}

.square {
height: 250px;
width: 250px;
background: #1abc9c;
border: none;
transition: .2s;
}

.square:active {
border: solid 50px #000;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8vmkychx/embedded/result/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to transition from nothing to something which doesn't work.

Try defining the border with zero width and then transition

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.square {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  background: #1abc9c;
  border: 0px solid seagreen;
  transition: .5s;
}
.square:active {
  border: 50px solid seagreen;
```

```html
<div class="square"></div>
```

Comment: Oh this looks nice ! i'll try it that way thank you a lot. Btw, do you think i can do the same with a padding ?

Answer (score 1):

It happens because you've set the border to none. Add a `50px` transparent border to the `.square`

```
.square {
    border: solid 1px transparent;
    transition: .2s;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8vmkychx/3/

Comment: not exactly :s I like how the border animates. In fact I the want the border to do the same animation but in the other direction

Comment: In that case, set the border to 1px. Answer updated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change to :

```
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid red;
}

.square {
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    background: #1abc9c;
    border: solid 0px #000;
    transition: .2s;
}

.square:active {
    border: solid 50px #000;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kqnotw5k/

Answer (score 0):

Paulie_D's answer worked great, I've also tried it with a padding and it works as well

```
<div class="squarecontainer"><div class="square"></div>

* {
box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.squarecontainer {
height: 250px;
width: 250px;
transition: .2s;
padding: 0;
background: #000;
}

.squarecontainer:active {
padding: 50px;
}

.square {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: #1abc9c;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8vmkychx/4/